# Adding your Page Tab App to your Page

Tags: facebook

Your https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL brings me to an error page.

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: if you are sure that you have enter the correct values in the dialog, just try again later. If you are not sure, go to your app settings and get the app_id and canvas page url for the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

"next" should be "redirect_uri"

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[APP-ID]&redirect_uri=[https://www.yourdomain

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook, using the &next= parameter is recommended practice: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

[image: From Facebook docs]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=https://facebook.com

hopefully help :)